# Three.js antialiasing not working on Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, three.js, webgl

I'm currently running Chrome v31 and antialiasing seems to not be working at all. No errors in either browsers.

Possibly relevant code:

```
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer( { antialias: true } );
```

In Safari it renders fine: [image: Properly aliased image]

vs Chrome:

[image: Shitty lines - Chrome]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to be a rendering issue with Chrome, perhaps you have the **32 bit** Chrome installed?

You can do two things to increase the quality.  First set a renderer attribute

```
renderer.shadowMapType = THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap; // options are THREE.BasicShadowMap | THREE.PCFShadowMap | THREE.PCFSoftShadowMap
```

and then you can also increase the shadowmap size of your light with:

```
light.shadowMapWidth = 1024; // default is 512
light.shadowMapHeight = 1024; // default is 512
```

as seen in the issue here: [Quality of Three.js shadow in Chrome/MacOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16752075/quality-of-three-js-shadow-in-chrome-macos)

*“ I believe that this depends on the browser and system you are using. As far as i know, Firefox doesn't support antialiasing right now at all. Also it may be dependant on your graphics card and drivers. For example, i don't get antialiasing in Chrome on my old mid 2009 MacBook Pro, but i do get antialiasing on my newer late 2012 machine.*

*Also, you may consider using the FXAA shader to do the antialiasing as a postprocessing step. You can read about postprocessing here. ”*

Read more: [Antialiasing not working in Three.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17224795/antialiasing-not-working-in-three-js)

Comment: Oh wow I skipped right over that question because I (thought) didn't care about shadows.. I'll give it a try and report back.